# JVM Parallel Plugin Issue "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date"

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have attached my sample project structure, you can check the package name is also correct, my compiler and jre are of same version.`

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ CucumberTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:5.0.0:generateRunners (generateRunners) @ CucumberTest ---
[INFO] Adding C:\Users\Bismillah\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.9.0.RELEASE\CucumberTest\target\generated-test-sources\cucumber to test-compile source root
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ CucumberTest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CucumberTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Bismillah\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.9.0.RELEASE\CucumberTest\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) @ CucumberTest ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.204 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-19T19:13:30+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### My POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.selenium.try</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <?m2e ignore?>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Mandatory -->
                            <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. -->
                            <glue>com.example</glue>
                            <!-- These are optional, with the default values -->
                            <!-- Where to output the generated tests -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, 
                                containing your feature files. -->
                            <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/FeatureFiles/</featuresDirectory>
                            <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written -->
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>

                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <name>json</name>
                                </plugin>

                            </plugins>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>@tag1</tag>
                            </tags>
                            <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of JUnit ones. -->
                            <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>

                            <!-- The class naming pattern to use. Only required/used if naming 
                                scheme is 'pattern'. -->
                            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                            <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per 
                                scenario. FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                            <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWHTU.png)

Test Resources are not getting generated and my scripts are not getting identified, i have tried multiple solutions. can any one help me on this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itLEw.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
As per the POM structure you have given ,include tag is as below-
<includes>
  <include>**/*IT.java</include>
</includes>

But as per the project structure your testrunner name is RunnerClass.java, so that 
should be`inside include tag. Seems you have copied the settings from the lick below 
but forgot to modify it.`
```

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html